# How to uninstall ubersvn in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, svn, uninstall

I cannot find a good/official way to do this in Ubuntu.

The best one I got from googling is this [post](http://www.svnforum.org/threads/39563-CentoOS-How-to-uninstall-and-reinstall?highlight=uninstall%20ubersvn).

So how can we completely remove UberSVN after installing it?

Comment: Sounds like it was not installed via the package manager, is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's not installed via the package manager, so it's going to need you to do two things to uninstall uberSVN completely (it would be good to know why you want to uninstall too?).

1. Stop uberSVN and apache, either via the UI or by using the control script -
   "/etc/init.d/ubersvncontrol stop" and "/etc/init.d/svnservercontrol stop" (or if you must, by killing the Tomcat process).
2. Delete all contents of /opt/ubersvn (the default install location, assuming you installed there).
3. Delete /etc/init.d/svnservercontrol and /etc/init.d/ubersvncontrol

That will remove all traces of uberSVN...

Comment: Don't forget to delete ubersvn linux user with: sudo userdel ubersvn

Answer (score 0):

Also, as **root** edit these files and remove the **uber*** user and group:

```
/etc/group
/etc/passwd
/etc/shadow
/etc/gshadow
```